# Referencing hash keys with a variable in perl

Tags: perl, hash, key

I am trying to create a Perl script that allows me access a hash key/value by using a variable.

The code below is a very high level example of script does. Is there any way to reference the key of the hash with a variable? It looks like the $hash_exmp{$temp_var} is not being accepted.

```
my %hash_exmp = (
    $key_1 => "file1",
    $key_2 => "file2",
    $key_3 => "file3",
);

for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
    for($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++){     
        print $j;            
        $temp_var = "key_${i}";
        print $hash_exmp{$temp_var};
    };
};
```

Comment: You've got a bunch of issues with this code (which would be highlighted if you `use strict; use warnings;`) which might explain the problem you are having. I don't know if they are the cause of your real problem or if your attempt to create a [mcve] is just showing a different set of problems.

Comment: Did you mean `$key_1 => "file1"` or rather `key_1 => "file1"` ?

Comment: If you are trying to use a variable to store a variable name, that is [a](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) [bad](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) [idea](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html).

Comment: The issue was making my keys as variables when I changed them to string names it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you want something like this:

```
my %hash_exmp = (
    'key_1' => "file1",
    'key_2' => "file2",
    'key_3' => "file3",
);
for(my $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
    print $hash_exmp{'key_'.$i} . "\n";
}
```

Comment: And `for(my $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)` can be simplified to `for my $i (1..3)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was making my keys as variables when I changed them to string names it works. In other words I changed from $key1 => "file1" to key1 => "file1"

Comment: You can use a variable for a key in a hash, `my %h = ($key_name => 1)` but that variable must be defined beforehand (`my $key_name = 'id';`) and then it will be evaluated and your "actual" key is that (the string `'id'` in this example). Then you can work with it using a variable as well, `$h{$var}`, as long as that `$var` evaluates to the string `'id'`, for `$h{id}` (may drop quotes for a hash key when it's a clean literal).  If you don't know whether a key exists for a string that a variable evaluates to then you can check, `if (exists $h{$var}) ... `.